# Laravel Route resource named functions

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I currently have routes like this

```
//Settings
Route::prefix('settings')->group(function(){
    //Get all users settings
    Route::resource('user', 'SettingsController');
});
```

Which will produce a list of routes like so

```
| POST      | settings/user                     |user.store   | App\Http\Controllers\SettingsController@store                              | web,auth,GlobalAdmin        |
| GET|HEAD  | settings/user                     |user.index   | App\Http\Controllers\SettingsController@index                              | web,auth,GlobalAdmin        |
| GET|HEAD  | settings/user/create              |user.create  | App\Http\Controllers\SettingsController@create                             | web,auth,GlobalAdmin        |
```

And so on.

My issue is that I want the settings controller to be able to control a list of different settings in 1 controller, not just 'users'.

How would I name the resource so that it names the functions at the end?

For example, the above code generates function names like `SettingsController@store`, how would i get it so that it auto builds the function name with a prefix like `SettingsController@userstore`?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Unless you go behind the scenes and actually hack into how Laravel handles the generation. What you can do however is use `except` on the resource route or use [partial resource routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers#restful-partial-resource-routes).

Once you have done one of the above, you can just add your routes manually such as

POST settings/user
POST settings/other
POST settings/general

And point them that way.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Is this the cleanest way of achieving my goal? My main priority here is to keep my routes file nice and clean and as short as possible

Comment: @S_R I use partial resource routes for a bunch of stuff, if I have any extra routes beyond what resource can handle I just add the routes directly below.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to have such behavior you can have it. You can extend the `Illuminate\Routing\ResourceRegistrar` class and bind your extended version to the container.

There is only one method that needs to be adjusted, which is the method that sets up the `action` for each of the routes of the resource, `getResourceAction`. This can be adjusted to check for a key passed in the options array the the `ResourceRegistrar` already uses. If a key is present you can enable the behavior you need, prefixing the method name with the resource name and uppercasing the first letter of the actual method.

```
class YourRegistrar extends \Illuminate\Routing\ResourceRegistrar
{
    protected function getResourceAction($resource, $controller, $method, $options)
    {
        $name = $this->getResourceRouteName($resource, $method, $options);

        // check if 'pre' option was set
        $method = isset($options['pre']) ? $resource . ucfirst($method) : $method;

        $action = ['as' => $name, 'uses' => $controller.'@'.$method];

        if (isset($options['middleware'])) {
            $action['middleware'] = $options['middleware'];
        }

        return $action;
    }
}
```

In a Service Provider `@register` (binding your new class to the current `ResourceRegistrar`):

```
$this->app->bind(
    \Illuminate\Routing\ResourceRegistrar::class,
    \Where\Ever\YourResourceRegistrar::class
);
```

In a routes file:

```
Route::resource('user', 'SettingsController', ['pre' => true]);

// SettingsController@userIndex
// SettingsController@userShow
// ...

Route::resource('user', 'SettingsController');

// SettingsController@index
// SettingsController@show
// ... normal
```

The router checks to see if there is something bound to the name of the `ResourceRegistrar` on the container before newing up one. If there is a binding it asks the container to resolve one. This is how you can extend the `ResourceRegistrar` and the router uses your version.

In our version we are checking if the options key `pre` was set or not. If it was we adjust the method names for the routes accordingly. (`$method = isset($options['pre']) ? $resource . ucfirst($method) : $method;`)

You can read more on the `ResourceRegistrar` and more detail of what happened above in my blog article on the subject:

[asklagbox blog - Resource Registrar - lets extend](https://asklagbox.com/blog/resource-registrar#lets-extend)

Comment: Ahh brilliant, this looks great! Is this the function that `::resource` runs directly? So could i add a boolean to the function to only append on if I specify `true` in the function like `Route::resource('user', 'SettingsController', true);` ?

Comment: If you plan on using this more then once a real class can be created and a new macro could be added to the Router to call this similar to `Route::resource` ... depends what you want to do

Comment: Ok brilliant, do you have a link to the documentation (if available) to create a custom class and new macro?

Comment: give me a sec and i will show you a simple way to take advantage of the options array to do this without needing to do much else